# Android端末の外部ストレージにフォルダが作れない

Tags: android, java

```
1　String folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/data";
2　File dir = new File(folder);
3　// フォルダが無ければ作成
4　if(!dir.exists()){
5　　boolean result = dir.mkdirs();
6　　if(!result){
7　　　return false;
8　　}
9　}
```

上記のコードを実行すると、
1行目では、folder = "/storage/emulated/0/data"
5行目では、result = false
と、フォルダ作成に失敗してしまいます。
回避方法を教えていただけますか？

テスト端末は Nexus6 (Android6.0.1)　です。

以下のことを試しました。

1) Android5.x以下の端末では正常に処理されフォルダが作成されます。
2) 親フォルダ「emulated」や「0」に対して `canWrite()` を実行すると戻り値はfalseとなる。
3) 親フォルダ「emulated」や「0」に対して `setWritable(true, false)` を実行しても 2) の結果は変わりません。
4) Android Device Monitor の「File Explorer」でフォルダ「xxx」追加を試みると、

```
New Folder Error
Reason: mkdir:'/storage/emulated/xxx': Permission denied
```

が表示されます。
/storage/emulated のPermissionは「drwx--x--x」です。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 6.0からアプリ起動後、機能を使用するときにパーミッションを与えるようになっていますが、対応していますか？Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE　ですが

Comment: Android6.0からの変更点は知りませんでした。
調べて対応します。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

```
REQUEST_CODE = 200;    
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
  activity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

こんな感じでPermissionを付与してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: REQUEST_CODE でイベントがとれるのですね。
参考にさせていただき、試してみます。